# What if we heated the universe to a temperature above the Higgs phase transition?

Tags: standard-model

If it were possible to get the Universe, or a subset of it, back to the energy scale where spontaenous symmetry breaking and the electro-weak transition happened, what would happen?

Would we see phenomena mediated by $W^1, W^2, W^3$ and $B$?

If we then went "back down" in energy scale , would the VEV of the Higgs field be the same?

Comment: But isn’t the electroweak scale ~170 GeV? The LHC works at 7 TeV?

Comment: Yes, this is the order of magnitude electroweak scale, it happened once as the unvierse expanded, the vev  for the higgs field is 246 GeV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> The separation of the [four fundamental forces](https://phys.libretexts.org/?title=TextBooks_%26_TextMaps/University_Physics_TextMaps/Map:_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map:_University_Physics_III_-_Optics_and_Modern_Physics_(OpenStax)/11:_Particle_Physics_and_Cosmology/11.7:_Evolution_of_the_Early_Universe) in the early universe.

You are asking whether one can reproduce the state of the universe before $10^{-12}$ seconds, when the weak and electromagnetic forces start to separate. Note that the black body temperature is $10^{15}$ K  at 100 GeV (order of magnitude of the electroweak breaking scale).

This is  not something that can be attained in a laboratory.

Then your question becomes metaphysical, i.e. if the same physics laws would hold in all possible universes.